# using the criteria for finding data in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I'm using the criteria for finding data from database and I have duplicate data in some columns. I want to show only one of them when using criteria.
I can't use **listDistinct** because i have max and offset in the list.

```
Domain.createCriteria().list(max: pageSize, offset: offset) {

            distinct('column has duplicate')
        }
```

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: how would you put your HQL query to look for data?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe the relationships that `Domain` has which relate to the entities that you want to weed out duplicates of.